# какие вопросы нужно задать самому себе, чтобы понять хранить величины в разных таблицах или в одной таблице

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Описание:
Получил задание спроектировать БД для учета погоды. Прочитал заново книгу, посмотрела материалы, но не смог найти ответы на свои вопросы.

Коротко о проектируемой БД:

1. Данные о погоде могут прийти как за одну величину, так и за несколько величин. Пример:

   - Скорость среднего ветра, всегда приходит с данными о направлении среднего ветра;
   - Максимальная скорость ветра приходит всегда отдельно или вместе с данными о скорости среднего ветра
   - Может прийти данные "Высота нижней границы облаков измеренная инструментально" или "Высота нижней границы облаков измеренная визуально". Причем состав данных (enum) у них разный.
2. Проектируемая БД для системы которая:

   - будет отображать погоду в заданной точке (станции), так и на определенной зоне;
   - будет отображать погоду в заданной точке за одну или несколько величин (при наличии данных), в зоне только по одной из выбранных величин;
   - должна отображать прошедшую погоду (редко используемая функция). К примеру, если случится какая-та чрезвычайная ситуация, смотрят какая погода была в заданной точке (районе) в день ЧС

Вопросы:

А. Не могу понять, в одной таблице хранить все величины или каждую величину в своей таблице? ломаю голову уже не одну неделю;

Б. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие вопросы нужно задать самому себе, чтобы понять хранить величины в разных таблицах или в одной таблице?

**Примечание от 06.08.2018:**
Мне нужно построить модель которая максимально была бы приближена к будущей БД, не могу понять какие себе вопросы нужно задать чтобы понять разделять или в 1-2 классах все ввести все это.

Основная цель:

- хранить полученные данные
- показать какая сегодня погода
- выделить зоны с опасными явлениями или критическими значениями к примеру, "показать зону где температура превышает 35 градусов и т.д.
- показать прошедшую погоду (редко используемая функция)

Вывел все метеоэлементы (температура, облачность и т.д.) в отдельный классы, чтобы избежать лишнего обновления данных всех таблиц.

Примеру:

1. Вчера пришла сводка: **Температура 15 градусов, Скорость ветра 10 м/с. Направление ветра 45 градусов.**
2. Сегодня, 06.08.2018, пришли данные только по температуре 25 градусов. В итоге должно отобразится погода так:

   - **Погода на 06.08.2018 Температура 25 градусов Скорость ветра 10 м/с**
   - **по состоянию на 05.08.2018 Направление ветра 45 градусов по состоянию на
     05.08.2018**

Второй вариант, который крутится у меня в голове, это я все значения "положил в один класс" Метеоэлементы. Но здесь смущает, то что все данные хранятся в одной таблице. И если нужно будет обновить к примеру только температуру, то как я понимаю всю таблицу нужно будет обновлять...

Comment: Вам только таблицу спроектировать в [реляционной] базе данных или вы на каком-то [объектном] языке программирования будете работать с ней? Задание явно учебное, поэтому неплохо понимать, что с вас просят. Вы спрашивали недавно за DDD, поэтому хорошо бы понимать, у вас уже есть предметная область (она по DDD должна проектироваться раньше, чем база - и потом отображают объектную модель в реляционную, как правило приводя к 3 нормальной форме) или вам дали задание в пустоте спроектировать структуру БД?

Comment: Попробуйте применить следующий подход. Каждая программная система получает данные на вход, как-то их обрабатывает и что-то отдаёт на выход. Что у вас на входе, откуда и какие берутся данные? Откуда-то с прибора каждые пять минут поступает документ "Замер" содержащий данные о времени замера, геоточке где снят замер, данные о ветре и осадках?

Comment: @AK модель для реляционной БД. Состав данных известен, не могу понять как лучше сделать, разделить или в одну таблицу все положить

Comment: О, я смотрю вы добавили два варианта. Это уже более предметный разговор. Давайте я вам сегодня вечером посмотрю и напишу своё мнение.

Comment: @AK да обновил. Хорошо спасибо. Меня пока мучает вопрос, метеоэлементы учитывать в одной таблице или разделить по разным? В одной таблице, да логично, но наверное каждый раз обращаться к одной таблице со всеми параметрами чтобы обновить одну или несколько полей, будет не очень хорошо? Хотя я могу ошибаться..

Comment: Я смотрю на систему справа и не понимаю, что вы понимаете под словом "метеоэлемент"? Это какой-то кусок железа ("метео микросхема"), которая бывает разных типов (одна выдаёт ветер, другая - осадки, третья - температуру) или это синоним для "МетеоСущность" (MeteoEntity), просто абстрактная группировка полей, не несущая никакого физического смысла? У меня впечатление, что вы запихнули по-максимуму в одну таблицу всё подряд, не глядя на физический смысл и эту таблицу можно назвать "МетеоВсё" и действительно - ой, всё... (

Comment: @Mike это синоним для "Метеосущность"

Comment: @Mike да получается запихнул...а можно как-то иначе?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что Вам не хватает теории по реляционным БД, а именно, что такое *нормализация*.
Не плохая книга - "Понимание SQL" Мартина Грубера, или можно, например, начать [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком виде вопрос слишком общий, на него сложно дать хороший и однозначный ответ. Могу только задать направление.

Отталкиваться в любом случае надо от **законченного** списка требований и описания данных. Выпишите все данные, которые могут прийти хотя бы теоретически. Потом попробуйте как-то обобщить. Что у них есть общего, чего нет. Добавьте к этому остальные данные, которые есть у вас.

Потом посмотрите на требования. Какие операции надо делать с данными, какие результаты должны быть, как их выводить.

Дальше вам надо выделить основные сущности, с которыми вы будете работать. У каждой сущности будут какие-то атрибуты, каждый из которых может быть либо новой сущностью, либо простым атрибутом. (Тут проблема в том, что одна и та же "сущность" в одной задаче будет простым атрибутом, а в другой может оказаться сложной сущностью, состоящей из многих других.)

Например, у вас данные о погоде. К вам приходит информация о температуре, скорости ветра, давлении. Что у них общего?

- это показания приборов
- они имеют числовые значения
- они имеют погрешность
- измеренные значения выражены в каких-то единицах измерения
- они относятся к какой-то точке пространства и времени (место, в котором стоял измерительный прибор и время, когда с него сняли показания)

Очевидно, что в данном случае, если мы имеем информацию вида "01.01.2018 в 08:00 в селе Кукуево было -20 С", значения `-20` и `01.01.2018` являются простыми атрибутами, они не представляют никакой самостоятельной ценности. А вот с `село Кукуево` немного сложнее. Возможен вариант, когда это простой атрибут. Это когда вам вообще не интересно, что там за село, это просто точка на карте. А возможен другой вариант, когда в этом селе есть метеостанция, там есть куча приборов, персонал и т. п., и все это вам тоже надо обрабатывать в вашей БД, и тогда это будет отдельная полноценная сущность.

И еще, по поводу законченности требований. Тут нужно быть аккуратнее, потому что если новые требования появляются постоянно по чуть-чуть и их поток сравним с тем, что уже реализовано, часто возникает ситуация, когда работа какая-то идет, но внешне кажется, что постоянно "еще не готово", и совершенно непонятно, когда будет готово. Тут нужно уметь вовремя сказать начальству "нет, давайте вы сначала перечислите все, что нужно, а потом начнем". Правда, чтобы уметь аргументировать такие вещи, надо опыт разработки иметь. Еще хорошо бы разбить все на этапы, и каждый этап отрабатывать отдельно.

**UPD**
ИМХО, брать второй вариант и не мучиться. Как я понимаю, данные приходят (или не приходят) все вместе. Если какие-то данные не пришли, писать в соответствующий столбец `NULL`. При выводе - обрабатывать (то есть просто не выводить какой-то показатель, если данных нет). Если данные будут раскиданы по разным таблицам, придется делать по одному селекту из каждой (или джойнить), при записи - соответственно, несколько инсертов/апдейтов вместо одного. А выигрыша никакого.
Целиком таблицу вы в любом случае обновлять не будете.

Comment: источники описаны. состав данных известен. Источников несколько, состав данных наблюдений почти совпадает с составом данных прогнозных. Поэтому объединил факт и прогноз в одну таблицу.

Comment: обновил основной текст вопроса. В пункте "примечание" и прил. концепт схему. По возможности посмотрите пож-та. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Вы как эксперт по разработке БД, можете подсказать: все в одну таблицу складывать или все таки разделить? Как в рисунке выше? метеорологических величин ориентировочно около 20. За день может прийти данные как за все величины, но отдельными файлами, Так и за 1-2 величины.  Отображать последнюю актуальную информацию.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

В поступающих потоках данных я вижу две постоянные величины: **место_замера** (читай геоточка или населённый пункт) и **дата** (или дата+время_замера). Без этих параметров ***никакие данные с мест не поступают***: личный опыт работы в ЦГМС. Это два дополнительных индекса (помимо индекса самой записи). Поэтому и осуществляем выборку по ним. Следовательно, хранить все поступающие данные проще в одной таблице. Соответственно, каждые новые данные **не изменяют** таблицу, а лишь дополняют её новой записью.

Comment: Интересный опыт работы! ;) спасибо за совет.

Comment: Не за что, удачи в разработке

Comment: Да. Рекомендовал бы в Access сделать тестовую версию. Посмотрите как обрабатываются данные, как вносятся новые и т.п. На этой основе уже сможете более чётко представить какая структура базы будет лучше...